# hql query to fetch data and sum of amount

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hql

I am writing query to fetch data from tables

my hql query is

```
SELECT distinct bd FROM BillDetails AS bd
    LEFT JOIN FETCH bd.customerDetails AS cd
    LEFT JOIN FETCH bd.billProductList AS bpd
    LEFT JOIN FETCH bpd.product AS pd
    WHERE bd.billNo=:id
    AND bd.client.id=:cid
```

Above query is working properly

I want to write query to fetch sum of all amount field of `billPaidDetailses`.

`billPaidDetailses` is a list in `BillDetails` class.

I am trying following query for that but it is not working

```
String hql = "select distinct bd,sum(bpds.amount) from BillDetails as bd "
                    + "left join fetch bd.customerDetails as cd "
                    + "left join fetch bd.billProductList as bpd "
                    + "left join fetch bpd.product as pd "
                    +"left join fetch bd.billPaidDetailses as bpds "
                    + "where bd.billNo=:id "
                    + "and bd.client.id=:cid ";
```

The error returned is

```
org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch 
    multiple bags
```

Comment: Are you sure that aggregate function, this case `sum()` can be used with `join`?

Comment: How try with this query `select sum(bpd.amount) from BillDetails as bd left join fetch bd.customerDetails as cd left join fetch bd.billProductList as bpl left join fetch bpd.product as pd left join fetch bd.billPaidDetailses as bpd where bd.billNo=:id and bd.client.id=:cid`

Comment: @suninsky see updated query

Comment: Sigh, yet another "is not working". Why don't you post the error you get and greatly increase the chance of actually getting help? Its not like people can simply take your HQL and execute it for themselves to see what's going on.

Comment: @Gimby I tried my query againg it is showing `org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags`

Comment: I think Query is correct(I have updated correct query).Showing another exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [Hibernate manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-aggregation):

> Hibernate also does not currently expand a grouped entity, so you
>   cannot write group by cat if all properties of cat are non-aggregated.
>   You have to list all non-aggregated properties explicitly.

It means you will have to add all properties for all joined entities:

- BillDetails bd
- bd.customerDetails cd
- bd.billProductList bpd
- bpd.product pd

giving you a HQL query like:

```
select distinct bd, sum(bpds.amount) 
from BillDetails as bd "
left join fetch bd.customerDetails as cd
left join fetch bd.billProductList as bpd
left join fetch bpd.product as pd
left join fetch bd.billPaidDetailses as bpds
where 
    bd.billNo=:id and bd.client.id=:cid
group by
    bd.id,
    bd.propertyA,
    bd.propertyB,
    cd.id,
    cd.propertyC,
    cd.propertyD,
    pd.id,
    pd.propertyE,
    pd.propertyF,
    bpds.id,
    bpds.propertyG,
    bpds.propertyH
```

The only advantage over a native SQL query is that Hibernate manages to regroup entities in a hierarchical structure.