# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to iland.hbm.BillDetails`

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Following are my code where I am fetching data from multiple table and want to print that data.

For fetching data I am using following method

```
 public List<BillDetails> fetch(long id, long cid) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List<BillDetails> obj = null;
        try {
            String hql = "select distinct bd,sum(bpds.amount) from BillDetails as bd "
                    + "left join fetch bd.customerDetails as cd "
                    + "left join fetch bd.billProductSet as bpd "
                    + "left join fetch bpd.product as pd "
                    + "left join fetch bd.billPaidDetails as bpds "
                    + "where bd.billNo=:id "
                    + "and bd.client.id=:cid ";

            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter("id", id);
            query.setParameter("cid", cid);
            obj = query.list();
            tx.commit();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Size is " + obj.size());
        System.out.println("  " + obj.get(0).getBillNo());
        return obj;
    }
```

BillDetails pojo

```
public class BillDetails implements java.io.Serializable {
 private Long billNo;
    private CustomerDetails customerDetails;
    private Client client;
    private BigDecimal subTotal;
    private BigDecimal vat;
    private BigDecimal total;
    private String invoiceNo;
    private Date invoiceDate;
    private String status;
    private Timestamp addDate;
    private Set<BillPaidDetails> billPaidDetails = new HashSet(0);
     private Set<BillProduct> billProductSet = new HashSet(0);
    //getter and setter
   }
```

BillPaidDetails

```
public class BillPaidDetails implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private Client client;
    private BillDetails billDetails;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private String paymentMode;
    private Date dt;
    private Timestamp adddate;
}
```

While printing value at `fetch()` at `System.out.println("  " + obj.get(0).getBillNo());`
It is showing
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to iland.hbm.BillDetails`.

How to resolve above exception and where the `sum(bpds.amount)` will store.
Is it possible that `sum(bpds.amount)` should be store in any desired fields of `BillPaidDetails` like added a field `private BigDecimal totalAmount;` where sum will stored.

Comment: you can directly do this : obj.getBillNo();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this query can't work as it is. [I already responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673129/hql-query-to-fetch-data-and-sum-of-amount/24674394#24674394) about the need for including all fetched entities' properties in the group by clause.

You try to select both an entity and a sum, while expecting to fit into a `List<BillDetails>`.

If you were only selecting `BillDetails` you'd be fine. But when you want to select more than one entity you need to assign the select to a `List<Object[]>`:

```
List<Object[]> obj = null;
...
Object[] bdAndSum = obj.get(0);
BillDetails bd = (BillDetails) bdAndSum.get(0);
Number sum = (Number) bdAndSum.get(1);
```